# Number of comparison in Quick Sort

Tags: quicksort

I want to ask theoretically ( not considering comparisons in loop ) how the number of comparison differs in case of sorted array. Let there is an implementation which selects last elements as pivot element.
Now an array of length 10 is given. Here I am just talking about indexes.
1> If array is sorted: 10 the element is pivot and total comparisons are 9.( for a particular implementation ):
a) `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <10>` comp = 9 ( considering till 9th element)
b) `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 <9> 10` comp = 8 ( pivot is 9 )....and so on
so total comparisons = 9 + 8 + 7 +...1 ~ n^2

2> If we are given some permutation such that every time we get pivot as middle of the array.
a) `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <10>` comp = 9 ( pivot = 10 )
Now let it get partitioned at middle
b) We get these two partitions `1 2 3 4 <5>`    `6 7 8 <9> 10` comp = 4 + 3 = 7
...and so on .

I am not seeing that much difference in these two .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the depth of recursion, not the number of compares per level of recursion. Assume pivot is excluded from further recursions, the first case is 9 levels of recursion, 45 compares, the second case is 3 levels of recursion, 19 compares:

```
 1  2   3   4  <5>  6   7   8   9   10   -  9 compares
 1 <2>  3   4       6   7  <8>  9   10   -  7 compares
 1     <3>  4      <6>  7      <9>  10   -  3 compares
                                         ------------
                                           19 compares
```

---

The ideal size for quicksort where pivot is excluded from recursion is 2^k-1 elements. Consider 15 elements (shown in hex). The first case is 14 levels of recursion, 105 compares. The second case is 3 levels of recursion, 34 compares:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7  <8>  9   a   b   c   d   e   f   - 14 compares
 1   2   3  <4>  5   6   7       9   a   b  <c>  d   e   f   - 12 compares
 1  <2>  3       5  <6>  7       9  <a>  b       d  <e>  f   -  8 compares
                                                             -------------
                                                             - 34 compares
```